# How to trap when server forcebly closes HttpClient

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

One is encouraged to re-use HttpClient rather than making a new one for each api call.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

My client program has a single connection that remains open.
However, if somebody stops IIS then the connection can't remain open.

In this case I get an exception that kills my client program even though I have a catch for it. (see code)

Is there some way to make the exception handler handle the exception without crashing the program?

Alternatively, is there some property of HttpClient that indicates that the server has closed it?

```
try
{
    return await m_Client.GetAsync(AppVars.Instance.ServerAddress + method);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  // getting 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host' kills the 
  // application

  // getting 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'
  // does not kill the application - i.e. catch behaves as expected
}
```

Comment: Why would catching an exception kill the application?

Comment: with http request the connection gets served or faulted but cant forever engage a single client. If you connection got closed for some reason then you should apply some retry mechanism in your code level.

Comment: @mm8 I don't think catching the exception is what is killing the application. My guess is that HttpClient is doing something extra that kills the application when the exception happens.

Comment: So it throws an exception that you catch *and* also kills the app? I doubt it.

Comment: @Manti_Core - but I cannot catch when the connection is severed because the application is being killed.

Comment: @mm8 that is exactly what is happening, even if I have a breakpoint set on it.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that this is caused by Visual Studio. I am debugging both the client and the server from one solution (multiple startup projects). When I close IIS Express, Visual Studio kills the client next time it tries to use the connection. If I launch a separate instance of Visual Studio and debug the client from there then the client does not get killed when I try to re-use the closed connection, i.e. the exception handling works as expected. (so I can make a new connection and retry)

Hopefully this will help anyone who experiences the same issue.